# Metro Builder doesn't launch in web browser just in terminal

Tags: node.js, react-native, uninstallation

I am unable to uninstall react-native 8.15.0.
I used command npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

I get the following back:
up to date, audited 1 package in 203ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

I ran
npm react-native --version
version 8.15.0 shown

Computer: Windows 10, Node.js v16.13.0., react-native 8.15.0

Answer (score 0):

8.15.0 is your npm version. [react-native-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli) does not have a version 8.15.0.
Also the command `npm react-native --version` spits out npm version. Try doing `npm version` without the react-native part, it will output the same version. My guess is it simply ignores the react-native part.
Please refer to npm [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config) for more info.

Comment: Looking at the package.json : react-native": "0.68.2" is the version installed. NPM version 8.15.0  from the terminal and version 8.11.0 from VS code terminal

Comment: Is you issue resolved or not. What exactly is the issue that you are facing? The question title seems different from the description.
Have you tried simply entering url localhost:8081 in your web browser after running npm start? What result do you get ?